# Trouble integrating MobiPick date picker into custom form that already has a div with data-role="page"

Tags: jquery, date, mobile

I am very new to Javascript and jQuery but want to integrate the nice date picker below into our form.

http://mobipick.sustainablepace.net/demo-advanced.html

Trouble Code:

```
$(document).on( "pagecreate", "#demo", function() {
var picker = $( "input[type='text']", this );
picker.mobipick();
});



<div id="demo" data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true">
<div data-role="content" >
<div class="demo">
<input type="text" />
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The problem is that it only runs the function on pagecreate and passes the "this" which I don't know what that is actually passing. My form already has a main `<div data-role="page">` and when I add another div with `<div id="demo" data-role="page">` the that second div doesn't display. If I change it to `<div id="demo" data-role="subpage">` then it displays but then the function above doesn't fire.

Answer (score 2):

Someone else posted this code which works perfectly.

Javascript

> ```
>           $(document).ready(function () {
>             var picker = $("#StartDate", this);
>             picker.mobipick();
>             picker.bind("change", function () {
>                 var date = $(this).val();
>             // formatted date                   
>             var dateObject = $(this).mobipick("option", "date");
>             });
>             });
> ```

Html

```
<input name="StartDate" id="StartDate"  type="text" value=""/>
```